# Какой сервис использовать для получения данных о погоде через API?

Tags: api

Подскажите, толковый ресурс с нормальным api, где можно взять погоду по городам России на текущее время.

Comment: @ukroficer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Очень хороший ресурс: [OpenWeatherMap - free weather data and forecast API](http://openweathermap.org/)
А так же есть API у яндекса: [Яндекс.ТвояПогода](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136149/)

Answer (score 4):

- [Comparing Weather APIs](http://michaelwelburn.com/2011/11/02/comparing-weather-apis/)
- [Прогноз погоды для сайта через API Яндекса](http://maarkus.ru/prognoz-pogody-dlya-sajta-cherez-api-yandeksa/)

Answer (score 3):

[Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs)

Answer (score 2):

Остановился на `yahoo`. Вот статья, но не могу понять, откуда брать код города: [Поговорим о погоде](http://habrahabr.ru/post/20461/)

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать [погодный информер](http://masterpro.ws/snova-maxmind-snova-pogodnye-informery-i-snova-ajax), умеющий самостоятельно определять город посетителя вашего сайта. Код можно взять по указанной ссылке, там же и демка. Информер работает на основе американского сервиса World Weather Online и maxmind.