# Брать информацию с сайта

Tags: php

**Как заставить PHP выводить информацию с другого сайта?** Надо, чтобы просто с сайта выводился текст. Вот так:

```
<?php
$tmturacode = file_get_contents ('http://??????/index.html');
(процессы, которые опишите)
echo $tmtura;
?>
```

**Суть:**
На сайте дюжина текста. Хочется, что-бы выводилось лишь одно переменяющиеся число.

извините, просто новичок в PHP

И да, хотел что-бы объяснили как это делается, а не написали все за меня.

Comment: `на сайте дюжина текста` и `одно число`: вы сами-то поняли что спрашиваете? Простой пример: "сегодня 16 августа 2015 года" - угадайте какое здесь число я хочу вывести? Так здесь всего два числа и я текст привел, а вы даже его не привели

Comment: Пожалуйста:  (ненужныйхлам)+18 °C(ненужныйхлам) Правда не совсем число, а string
И да, хотел что-бы объяснили как это делается, а не написали все за меня.

Comment: Хорошо, еще один пример: "Сегодня на улице было +28 °C, а у меня на балконе температура поднялась до +43 °C, а завтра обещают всего-то +18 °C, не больше". И вот что здесь именно является "ненужным хламом"? Задача, которую нельзя формализовать, поставлена неправильно. В текущем виде ответить на ваш вопрос нельзя, т.к. не понятно какое именно число из всей кучи текста вас интересует.

Comment: Еще раз говорю: хотел что-бы объяснили как это делается, а не написали все за меня. Я сам бы хотел выделить хлам.

Comment: я и не собираюсь делать что-то за вас, я просто прошу вас формализовать задачу так, чтобы ее можно было выполнить и при том решение было бы единственным. Например: "на сайте есть показатель температуры, он хранится в элементе `<div id='current-temperature'>ТЕКУЩАЯ ТЕМПЕРАТУРА</div>` Как получить значение, хранящееся в данном блоке?" Тогда было бы ясно что и как требуется сделать

Comment: Раз интересует погода, то вопрос можно закрывать как дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом приближении надо, получив html cтраницы, [прогнать](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) его через [регулярное выражение](http://habrahabr.ru/post/115825/), которое совпадёт только с искомым нужным текстом. Найденное совпадение отдать как результат.

Во втором приближении, если подумать, каждый раз скачивать страницу не обязательно, и хорошо бы полученную температуру хранить где-то у себя, и обновлять её всего раз в X минут.

Наконец, здравый смысл подсказывает, что вылавливать искомую строку в тексте большой страницы – лишняя работа и риск ошибок. В то время, как многие сервисы, связанные с погодой, имеют API, через которое не прочь отдавать чистые данные.

Comment: первое и второе приближение потерпит неудачу, т.к. на странице будет много таких чисел (температур), а какое (по какому признаку) именно надо выбрать - ТС так и не указал. И здравый смысл может подвести, если окажется, что это температура это только пример, либо требуется не температура где-то, а, например, температура в конкретном водоеме и получить ее можно только посетив определенный сайт без АПИ

Comment: да, спасибо. знаю о вещи под названием API, но, увы, у Яндекс.Погоды его нет. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Александр, так температуру можно и через другие сервисы получить,. Например, такую услугу предоставляет [gismeteo](https://www.gismeteo.ru/forweb.html), правда, платно, но можно поискать и другие, бесплатные

Comment: И кто сказал, что у яндекса этого нет? Есть, [знакомьтесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/136149/)

Comment: Ну вот опять HTML прогоняем через регулярное выражение :(

Answer (score 1):

> хотел что-бы объяснили как это делается

Пишите рецепт:

1. Берем страницу с нужного сайта, записываем в переменную;
2. Парсим переменную как HTML-DOM. Нужные инструменты: [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) или [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php) или ищем что-то еще в гугле по строке "php parse html";
3. Находим нужный элемент в дереве HTML;
4. (опционально) Отсекаем ненужное регулярными выражениями.

Этот процесс не самый простой с точки зрения нагрузки на сервер, поэтому это все необходимо кешировать и обязательно обрабатывать таймауты при запросе к стороннему серверу, поскольку он может не отвечать. Также могут появиться проблемы если на этом сервере поменяют структуру выводимой страницы или вплотную будут защищаться от парсинга данных.

Answer (score 0):

Как правило многие сайты погоды при клике на "вкладку дня" подгружают данные с помощью Ajax. Если просмотреть в дебаге куда и с какими переменными идет запрос,
тогда можно составить такой зарос самому и получать данные в чистом виде. Но это если сайт не использует всякие токены.